# How to set environment variable for ApolloClient that should be server side rendered for CI/CD

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, azure-pipelines, apollo-client

I have the following apolloClient

```
/**
 * Initializes an ApolloClient instance. For configuration values refer to the following page
 * https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#the-apolloclient-constructor
 *
 * @returns ApolloClient
 */
const createApolloClient = (authToken: string | null) => {
  const httpLinkHeaders = {
    ...(authToken && { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` })
  };
  console.log('CREATING APOLLO CLIENT WITH HEADERS >>>>', httpLinkHeaders);

  console.log(
    'Graph Env Variable URL >>>>>',
    publicRuntimeConfig.GRAPHQL_URL
  );

  

  return new ApolloClient({
    name: 'client',
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: createHttpLink({
      uri: publicRuntimeConfig.GRAPHQL_URL,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: httpLinkHeaders
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
};

/**
 * Initializes the apollo client with data restored from the cache for pages that fetch data
 * using either getStaticProps or getServerSideProps methods
 *
 * @param accessToken
 * @param initialState
 *
 * @returns ApolloClient
 */
export const initializeApollo = (
  accessToken: string,
  initialState = null,
  forceNewInstane = false
): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> => {
  // Regenerate client?
  if (forceNewInstane) {
    apolloClient = null;
  }

  const _apolloClient = apolloClient || createApolloClient(accessToken);

  // for pages that have Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client,
  // the initial state gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
    const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract();

    // Restore the cache using the data passed from
    // getStaticProps/getServerSideProps combined with the existing cached data
    _apolloClient.cache.restore({ ...existingCache, ...initialState });
  }

  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient;

  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;
  return _apolloClient;
};

/**
 * Hook to initialize the apollo client only when state has changed.
 *
 * @param initialState
 *
 * @returns
 */
export const useApollo = (
  initialState: any
): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    if (process.browser) {
      const accessToken = extractCookie(document.cookie, 'access_token');
      return initializeApollo(accessToken, initialState);
    }

    // document is not present and we can't retrieve the token but ApolloProvider requires to pass a client
    return initializeApollo(null, initialState);
  }, [initialState]);
};
```

That is initialized in the _app.tsx file like so

```
const updateApolloWithNewToken = useCallback(
    (accessToken: string) => {
      // Initialize apollo client with new access token
      setClient(
        initializeApollo(accessToken, pageProps.initialApolloState, true)
      );
      // Show the dashboard
      router.replace('/dashboard');
    },
    [router]
  );
```

With the following Next Config

```
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  console.log('Phase >>>>', phase);
  if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) {
    console.log('RETURNING DEVELOPMENT CONFIGURATION...');

    return {
      publicRuntimeConfig: {
        
        GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL
      }
    };
  }

  console.log('RETURNING PRODUCTION CONFIGURATION...');

  console.log('GRAPHQL_URL', process.env.GRAPHQL_URL);

  return {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      
      GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL
    }
  };
};
```

This is my _app.tsx

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  // Grab the apollo client instance with state hydration from the pageProps
  const router = useRouter();
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState);
  const [client, setClient] = useState(apolloClient);

  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Refresh token on browser load or page regresh
    handleAcquireTokenSilent();

    // We also set up an interval of 5 mins to check if token needs to be refreshed
    const refreshTokenInterval = setInterval(() => {
      handleAcquireTokenSilent();
    }, REFRESH_TOKEN_SILENTLY_INTERVAL);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(refreshTokenInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  
  const updateApolloWithNewToken = useCallback(
    (accessToken: string) => {
      // Initialize apollo client with new access token
      setClient(
        initializeApollo(accessToken, pageProps.initialApolloState, true)
      );
      // Show the dashboard
      router.replace('/dashboard');
    },
    [router]
  );

  return pageProps.isAuthenticated || pageProps.shouldPageHandleUnAuthorize ? (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <SCThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <StylesProvider injectFirst>
            <Component
              {...pageProps}
              updateAuthToken={updateApolloWithNewToken}
            />
          </StylesProvider>
        </SCThemeProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  ) : (
    <UnAuthorize />
  );
}

/**
 * Fetches the Me query so that pages/components can grab it from the cache in the
 * client.
 *
 * Note: This disables the ability to perform automatic static optimization, causing
 * every page in the app to be server-side rendered.
 */
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext: AppContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  const req = appContext.ctx.req;

  // Execute Me query and handle all scenarios including, unauthorized response, caching data so pages can grab
  // data from the cache
  return await handleMeQuery(appProps, req);
};

export default MyApp;
```

My problem is that when I run yarn build I get a server error generating 500 page. I know it is because when creating the Apollo Client it doesn't have access to the publicRuntimeConfig, it seems like Next is trying to build the ApolloClient when I run yarn build, I am using getInitialProps and getServerSideProps so I just want to access all the env variables on runtime not on build, because we want one build for our pipeline.

All other env variables in my app that are using publicRuntimeConfig are working, I tested by removing the env vars on build and adding them back on start and the app functioned as normal.

If there isn't a way to do this with apollo client, what would be reccomended to be able to pass different `uri`'s as env variables on start of the app not on build for Apollo Client or alternate solution?

Thanks for any help ahead of time

So I don't know if I have explained the problem well enough.

Basically the graphql URL is different depending on the environment it is in in development, staging, and production however they are supposed to use the same build so I need to access the GRAPHQL_URL via a runtime variable, but in my current setup it is just undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is redundant code and inefficiency. Primarily the hooks `updateApolloWithNewToken` and `useApollo` but also in the way you inject the `accessToken`.

I would recommend throwing the `ApolloClient` in it's own separate file and using it's configurable [links](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/) for your use-case.

However, the real problem most likely lies in the initialization of the client and your attempt at `memoizing` the client.

First, try updating the following,

```js
    link: createHttpLink({
      uri: publicRuntimeConfig.GRAPHQL_URL,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: httpLinkHeaders
    }),
```

to

```js
  link: createHttpLink({
    // ...your other stuff
    uri: () => getConfig().publicRuntimeConfig.GRAPHQL_URL
  })
```

If that doesn't work right away, I would recommend trying with the outmost minimal example.

Create a client you export, a provider and a component that uses it (without using state, useEffect or anything else). We can go from there if that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you [don't want to use](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration) `publicRuntimeConfig` because it adds overhead and is unnecessary for your use-case.  It also disables automatic static optimization.

Traditionally, environment variables are the way to handle dynamic settings based on the environment.  Next.js has three [default environments](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) – development, test, and production.

Your Next.js app will automatically grab (and merge) the correct variables depending on the environment.

.env.local

```
GRAPHQL_URL = localhost:8000/graphql
```

.env.test

```
GRAPHQL_URL = test.example.com/graphql
```

.env or .env.production

```
GRAPHQL_URL = production.example.com/graphql
```

Apollo config

```js
new ApolloClient({
 link: createHttpLink({
  uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
 })
});
```

---

#### Environment variable files

In your project root you can create files named

- `.env`
- `.env.local`
- `.env.test`
- `.env.test.local`
- `.env.production`

*I believe you can append `.local` to any environment to create a local only version `.env.production.local` - this has limited use in your case*

---

#### Next.js Environment variables

All environments - `.env`

- loaded in development, test, and production environments. This file is used for defaults across all environments.  The variables in this file will be overroad if another environment variable file has a variable with the same name.

[Development environment](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) `.env.local`

- loaded only when `NODE_ENV = development` (next dev)

[Test environment](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables) `.env.test`

- loaded only when `NODE_ENV = test`

[Test environment](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables) `.env.test.local`

- loaded only when `NODE_ENV = test` and local

Production environment `.env.production`

- loaded only when `NODE_ENV = production` (next start)

---

#### Example production only variable

Create a `.env.production` and add the variable there. You can repeat the same for test and local only variables.

---

#### Notes

It's good practice to add your .env to your `.gitignore` so you don't accidently commit secrets to your repositories.  At a minimum you should omit `.env*.local` files from git.

Depending on your CI/CD setup you can set your environment variables in the deployment platform like vercel, github actions, etc. This would allow you to set the test and production variables in the hosting platform and not in your code.

If you need an environment variable [accessible in the browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) you need to prefix the variabel with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`

Comment: Environment variables are injected and hence are not run-time compatible (they can not be changed). The question asks for run-time (and I guess an alternative solution if needed). This is what I would also recommend if you don't care for run-time injections.

Comment: This is a more standard approach over run-time variables in next.js.  The section Example production only variable specifically answers "what would be recommended to be able to pass different uri's as env variables on start of the app not on build"

Comment: @Anders Kitson can you clarify if you want the ability to change the environment variable of the fly or just want the ability to have different variables. As is, Sean's answer would require you to rebuild everytime you changed the env.

Comment: I need the variable for GRAPHQL_URL to be changeable in the app settings in azure at runtime because if it is a build we only are doing one build and that would cause each stage dev, staging and production to have the same url. I will try your strategy @urmzd in your answer thanks and report back

Comment: Each stage has its own variables (graphql url) defined in the corresponding env variable file. You only run one build and Next automatically grabs the correct env variable based on the stage. You will have 3 .env files in your root - one for each stage (see post).  Next.js does not recommend using publicRuntimeConfig to handle env variables. Check the first link in the post.